# Is there a way to multiply each node in a neural network layer by specific values? (Keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I am trying to modify the work of 'Concrete Autoencoders for Differentiable Feature Selection and Reconstruction'.

Here is the Keras code for the Concrete selector layer which is placed after the input layer for selecting important variables.

If you look at the code below, the return value Y becomes the inner product of X and K.transpose(self.selections), and the inner product values come out as much as the number of nodes.

```
class ConcreteSelect(Layer):
def __init__(self, output_dim, start_temp = 10.0, min_temp = 0.1, alpha = 0.99999, **kwargs):
    self.output_dim = output_dim
    self.start_temp = start_temp
    self.min_temp = K.constant(min_temp)
    self.alpha = K.constant(alpha)
    super(ConcreteSelect, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    
def build(self, input_shape):
    self.temp = self.add_weight(name = 'temp', shape = [], initializer = Constant(self.start_temp), trainable = False)
    self.logits = self.add_weight(name = 'logits', shape = [self.output_dim, input_shape[1]], initializer = glorot_normal(), trainable = True)
    super(ConcreteSelect, self).build(input_shape)
    
def call(self, X, training = None):
    uniform = K.random_uniform(self.logits.shape, K.epsilon(), 1.0)
    gumbel = -K.log(-K.log(uniform))
    temp = K.update(self.temp, K.maximum(self.min_temp, self.temp * self.alpha))
    noisy_logits = (self.logits + gumbel) / temp
    samples = K.softmax(noisy_logits)
    discrete_logits = K.one_hot(K.argmax(self.logits), self.logits.shape[1])

    self.selections = K.in_train_phase(samples, discrete_logits, training)
    Y = K.dot(X, K.transpose(self.selections))
    return Y

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)
```

This can be expressed graphically as image1 where K.transpose(self.selections) is represented as m.

[image: image1]

But what I want is just one vector of K.transpose(self.selections),

and multiply each input value (X) and K.transpose(self.selections) value and send to each node as in image2. (One connection per one input)

[image: image2]

As you might guess, I'm new to keras and need some help.
If you need further clarification on my question, I'll let you know.

Comment: Do you mean element wise multiplication?

Comment: Like, `X * K.transpose(self.selections)`

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen Yes and I want to send those element wise multiplications to each individual nodes in the next layer.

Comment: You may need to make a new Layer for this though if I understand you correctly. Basically what you want is a layer that do element-wise multiplication instead of matrix multiplication like `Dense` right?

Comment: Or you just want to replace `K.dot(X, K.transpose(self.selections))`?

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen Yes, I need to make a new layer for doing element-wise multiplication for each node. What I want to do is multiply the output of each node by a certain value (element of K.transpose(self.selections) as in figure 2.  I don't know how to make this in code.

Comment: `X * K.transpose(self.selections) ` doesn't work?

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen It doesn't work. (Dimensions error).  

Above code,  (as in figure 1), samples s concrete random variables like this: 
[_1^1,_2^1 _3^1…_^1], 
[_1^2,_2^2 _3^2…_^2], ...,
[_1^s,_2^s _3^s…_^s]
each concrete random variable is dot-producted with input data  [x_1...x_d].
So s dot-products are generated and go to the next layer.

Comment: But what I want is to sample only one concrete random variable .  I want to multiply elements of  [x_1...x_d] and [_1^1,_2^1 _3^1…_^1] and send those to the next layer as in figure 2...

Comment: Exactly what "Dimensions error" is? What does the code above do is obvious from the beginning. What you want to achieve on the other hand is not. From my point of view it's looks like you just want to multiplying 2 arrays so I asked you why not just do that.

Comment: What's more useful to solve this is what you have try, especially just multiply them directly, and what error it gave. Everything it printed out.

Comment: Also instead of some substitute letters that will look cool, writing the actual numeral values will make solving a problem a lot faster.